# Decrypt aes 128 encypted manifest .3mu8

Tags: encryption

i am trying to get a single video by a merge of multi .ts file and the relative manifest.3mu8

Here is the manifest:    (that i downloaded from the tab 'network' in chrome dev tools)

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://*WEBSITEHIDDEN*/?fv_player_hls_key=29d465f4-44f3-403a-93e1-788508301c3e",IV=0x93ddfa91c91b099b8dbd59c1747602de
#EXTINF:10.880000,
hls_8500_00000.ts
#EXTINF:10.800000,
hls_8500_00001.ts
...      00163.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

It's seems that it's used a AES-128 encryption, but is the key shown in the manifest? (key=29d465f4-44f3-403a-93e1-788508301c3e)

So...How i can merge all that ts files after after downloading them on my local computer?

Thank you to all, guys.

Sure you can help, have a good day

Rock'n'roll

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132088/how-to-decrypt-aes-128-encrypted-m3u8-video-files).

Comment: Already tried. Not working... Maybe I didnt understend

Comment: If you are confident this is the key and you also integrate the IV, then the issue could come from the key format. The dashes between numbers make it look like a GUID. There are conflicting standards for transforming a byte sequence into a GUID string. Windows based systems in particular will have some blocks in big endian and others in little endian. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Encoding The key could also be the ascii string of the GUID rather than the byte sequence.